# Could someone elaborate on this algebraic transformation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, transformation, fractions

I have a solution for an exercise and one part of it is not clear to me:

$
\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x - 1}} - 1}{x - 2} = \frac{1 - \sqrt{x - 1}}{(x - 2)\sqrt{x - 1}}
$

Could anyone explain, please, how the result was obtained?

The full solution is this:

$
\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x - 1}} - 1}{x - 2} = \frac{1 - \sqrt{x - 1}}{(x - 2)\sqrt{x - 1}} * \frac{1 + \sqrt{x - 1}}{1 + \sqrt{x - 1}} = \frac{2 - x}{(x - 2)\sqrt{x - 1}(1 + \sqrt{x - 1})} = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{x - 1}(1 + \sqrt{x - 1})}, x \ne 2
$

Comment: Multiply both the top and the bottom of the fraction by $\sqrt{x-1}$.  Remember you may always "multiply by one" and may always "add zero" without changing anything.  What exactly "one" looks like and what exactly "zero" looks like varies on what specific use you have intended for it.  Multiplying by $\frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt{x-1}}$ is such an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply multiply the top and bottom by $\sqrt{x-1}$:

$$\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}-1}{x-2}=\frac{\Bigl(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}-1\Bigr)\sqrt{x-1}}{(x-2)\sqrt{x-1}}=\frac{1-\sqrt{x-1}}{(x-2)\sqrt{x-1}}$$

Edit: This is valid as long as the thing you are multiplying top and bottom by is not $0$. In this case, $\sqrt{x-1} \neq 0$ for or else the thing you were given containing a $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}$ would have been undefined in the first place.

Comment: and may I ask why is it invalid to multiply by an expression, which can be equal to 0? Is it because this would introduce parasite roots? If so, why I can't just check a solution for those roots to exclude them?

Comment: If you multiply top and bottom by $0$, then in particular you would have multiplied the bottom by $0$, giving a $0$ denominator.

Comment: It's not just about excluding roots "parasite roots" - the whole thing doesn't make sense anymore. For example, you can't say $\frac 12=\frac{1 \times 0}{2\times 0}=\frac 00$

Answer (score 1):

In my retirement, I have been going to local high-schools as a volunteer, and I find, first, that the students have never been told this technique of simplifying a complicated fraction, and, second (much more discouragingly), that the teachers not only are unfamiliar with it, but also are unwilling to apply it.

Illustrative example:
$$
\frac{\frac12+\frac34}{\frac23-\frac16}=\frac{6+9}{8-2}=\frac{15}6=\frac52\,,
$$
the first step being achieved by multiplying top and bottom by $12$.